# How do I use CTE recursion to build an organization hierarchy?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a function that constructs a hierarchy for a given manager. It should return not just the people that report to the specified manager but also the people that report to those people and so on down the line.

My inclination is to go with a recursive CTE but I can't get it to work.

I've got a `ManagerAssignments` table that maps `ManagerUserIDs` to the `EmployeeIDs` of the employees they manage. `ManagerUserIDs` are `VARCHARs`, `EmployeeIDs` are `INT`. So a manager could have `UserID` 'Bob' and `EmployeeID` 1.

I've also got a `UserIDEmployeeIDMapping` table that relates a given `UserID` to
an `EmployeeID`. Not all employees have a `UserID`.

The `ManagerAssignments` table looks like this:

```
|ManagerUserID|EmployeeID|
|   Bob       | 1        |
|   Bob       | 2        |
|   Bob       | 3        |
|   Steve     | 4        |
|   Jim       | 5        |
|   Jim       | 6        |
|   Steve     | 7        |
```

The `UserIDEmployeeIDMapping` table looks like this:

```
|UserID|EmployeeID|
|Bob   |    10    |
|Steve |    1     |
|Jim   |    7     |
```

So if I select Bob I should get employees 1, 2, 3 and 4, since Steve reports to Bob. If I select Steve I should get 4, 5, 6 and 7 since Jim reports to Steve. If I select Jim I should just get 5 and 6.

A given employee is a leaf node if they don't have an entry in `UserIDEmployeeIDMapping` or they don't have a `ManagerUserID` entry in `ManagerAssignments`

What I'm struggling with is the extra level of indirection with having to see if a given employee has a `UserID`. I tried using a table variable to consolidate the two tables into one with `ManagerUserID`, `EmployeeID`, and `EmployeeUserID` fields and used that in the CTE. But I only get one hierarchy level that way.

```
DECLARE @UserID VARCHAR(150)
SET @UserID = 'Bob'

DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    ManagerUserID VARCHAR(150),
    EmployeeID INT,
    EmployeeUserID VARCHAR(150)
)

INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT MA.ManagerUserID, MA.EmployeeID, UE.UserID AS EmployeeUserID
FROM ManagerAssignments MA LEFT JOIN UserIDEmployeeIDMapping UE ON MA.EmployeeID = UE.EmployeeID

;WITH OrgChart (ManagerUserID, EmployeeID, EmployeeUserID) AS
(
        SELECT ManagerUserID, EmployeeID, EmployeeUserID
        FROM @Temp
        WHERE ManagerUserID = @UserID
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT T.ManagerUserID, T.EmployeeID, T.EmployeeUserID
        FROM @Temp AS T INNER JOIN OrgChart OC ON T.ManagerUserID = OC.ManagerUserID
        WHERE T.ManagerUserID <> @UserID
)
```

Expected output for `UserID` 'Bob':

```
|ManagerUserID|EmployeeID|EmployeeUserID|
|  Bob        |  1       | Steve        |
|  Bob        |  2       | NULL         |
|  Bob        |  3       | NULL         |
|  Steve      |  4       | NULL         |
```

Comment: For starters your ManagementAssignment table has a major normalization problem. You should store the Managers EmployeeID, not their name. If the name changes your data is a mess. But I don't really understand why you need two tables here. You don't have any examples where anybody has more than one manager so why not just have a column in the UserIDEmployeeIDMapping table for ManagerID which references the EmployeeID in the same table?

Comment: @SeanLange It's not their name, it's their active directory user ID. For your second question, not every user nor every employee is in UserIDEmployeeIDMapping table. Only those people who are both user's of the application and an employee of the relevant division of the company will be found there. There are some people who are users but not employee's for the purpose of the application and there are employees who are not users of the system.

Comment: But an AD username can and will change when people change their names. This is common with women who get married/divorced. This should still be a single table from what you are describing.

Comment: @SeanLange The design of the structure of the tables is irrelevant to the question. I have no authority over the DB structure.

Comment: I would argue that the structure is relevant because the thing that makes this the most difficult is the structure. But whatever, I will see if I can find a working query. What are you expecting as output? I know the rows for Bob but what columns?

Comment: @SeanLange Expected output is the Manager's User ID ('Bob' for Bob), the employee ID of someone who reports to him and that employee's User ID if it exists in the UserIDEmployeeIDMapping table.

So the first row for Bob should look like:

Bob, 1, Steve

Comment: @SeanLange The second row has no corresponding row in UserIDEmployeeIDMapping so it would be: Bob, 2, NULL

Comment: Instead of broken up examples of what you want in the comments can you post them in your question? The more I look at this the less I understand what you are after.

Comment: @SeanLange Sure. I've added the expected output for UserID Bob to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH cteOrgChart(ManagerUserID,ManagerEmployeeID,EmployeeID, EmployeeUserID)
AS(
  SELECT MA.ManagerUserID, UE.EmployeeID AS ManagerEmployeeID, MA.EmployeeID, EU.UserID AS EmployeeUserID
  FROM ManagerAssignments MA
  INNER JOIN UserIDEmployeeIDMapping UE 
  ON MA.ManagerUserID = UE.UserID
  INNER JOIN UserIDEmployeeIDMapping EU
  ON MA.EmployeeID=EU.EmployeeID
  WHERE MA.ManagerUserID='Bob'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT O.EmployeeUserID, O.EmployeeID, A.EmployeeID, M.UserID
  FROM cteOrgChart O
  LEFT JOIN ManagerAssignments A
  ON O.EmployeeUserID=A.ManagerUserID
  LEFT JOIN UserIDEmployeeIDMapping M
  ON M.EmployeeID=A.EmployeeID
  WHERE O.EmployeeID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT * FROM cteOrgChart;
```

Comment: I think there's a problem with the fields selected for the CTE. While you have ManagerUserID, ManagerEmployeeID and EmployeeID, it should be the Manager's UserID, the Employee ID of someone who reports to them and then the UserID of that employee if one exists for them in the UserIDEmployeeID mapping table. So this last field would be null for people who are not managers.

Comment: added the EmployeeUserID